# Formula to tile an irregular shape with a predefined number of squares

Tags: algorithm, apache-flex, math, shapes

I have a shape that is defined as a vector.  I am then provided with a number, which represents how many equal-sized squares I need to tile over my shape, in a series of rows. The X-coordinate of each square within the row does **not** need to be aligned with those of other rows.  I need to determine the required size of the squares, and their placement over the shape (X and Y) such that the interior of the shape is entirely covered, and on the perimeter, the majority of the area of each square is within the shape.

Does anyone know of any formula I could use to calculate this?  Or will I be earning my own PhD by working this one out?  :-)

Comment: In ActionScript, a vector is like an array, except all elements must have the same data type.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html .   Are you telling us you have an array of Shapes?  Or something else?  What have you tried to make this work?  Do you have code to share?

Comment: Some code would be very nice here.  The hard part seems to be "the majority of the area of each square is within the shape". I'll be thinking about it today.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com It would be difficult to give you code, its a fairly complex system, but to make things simple lets exclude my implementation of drawing the shape from the equation. In other words it does not matter how the irregular shape is drawn, it only matters that it can be draw as well as a predefined number of squares inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with iterative process:

PRELIMINARY NOTE: 
-I'm marking valriables names that I use later with the symbol <...> and in square brakets I note the dimension of the variable if it is an array.
- In round parenthesys you find iteration passages with ususally "i" as iteration counter.

GIVEN:

I1) array [2,n] of vertexes of a 2D straight edged figure:  (1:i:2, 1:j:n), so an array of ints dimensioned 2 x n.

I2) max number of used mesh elements to cover the figure: , so a scalar value

I3) the 2D OCS (Orthogonal Coordinate System) considered as reference for the vertex positioning: by default all the vertexes will provide the OCS by their own values.  Call it  fore reference, but it not really a variable.

OUTPUT:

O1) provided side length of square mesh covering the given shape at best: , so a scalar.

O2) the number of rows generated: , another scalar

O3) an array of X values of each string (a row) of squares, representing the lower left corner of the first square meshing element:  with 1:i:R, where R is the output mentioned before, so the number of generated rows by the algorithm.

O4) an array of integer containing the number of meshing elements per row:  with 1:i:R

HELPER FUNCTIONS:

//calculate cover factor

ACF: (average coverage factor), calculating the ration between the area of the whole original shape and the summation of all the array of squares generated (given the list of bottom left corners of squares add the side length).

SCF: (single element coverage factor): calculating the percentage of each single square area that is covered by (overlapping over) the shape. this is tricky but it can be computed with a little effort by triangulating in the Finite element meshing style (you can find meshing triangular elements techniques on line).

ALGO:

1) Define the minimum bounding box (the first square that contains the whole shape)

1.1) define the lowest Y shape point in the original OCS:   so a scalar representing the vertical offset between OCS0 and OCS1.

1.2) define the most left shape point (one of the vertexes) in the original OCS:

1.3) Shift the shape with the rigid linear transformation T:T(x,y) -> (x-dx, y-dy); now the bounding box has left bottom corner in the origin of new coodinate system (this is what maps OCS0 into OCS1)

1.4) shift the whole figure in the OCS1;

1.6) calculate Average Cover factor at step 0;

NOTE: this is already a solution, not the best but a mathematically acceptable solution.

1.7) check how many elements (there is only one at this stage) are fully included in the shape, call it   (in this first step this is zero), how many are fully excluded by the shape boundaries  (in this first step this is zero), and how many are partially overlapping  (in this first step this is 1). Note that during iterations the sum of the length of these three arrays has to be equal to the number of square generated by the refining of the bounding square.

1.8) remove all the squares from the grid that belong to NFULLOUT(0). At step zero this routine is not providing any result as there is only one partially covering element in the solution arrays.

2) Loop on refinement

2.1) calculate the refinement factor by RF =  M /( summation of QTY(1:R))

NOTE: the point 2.1 considers all full covering elements with weight 1 in the area computation as well as partial elements, a more precise way would use the SCF function on each single partially covering square to calculate the effective weight of the element to be used for grid area calculation.

2.2) calculate the new length of square side by L(1) = L(0)/ RF;

2.3) IF (the number of squares is lower than the allowed number of squares), refine the grid by regenerating the matrix of squares with the new side.

2.3.1)  check how many elements (there is only one at this stage) are fully included in the shape   (in this first step this is zero), how many are fully excluded by the shape boundaries  (in this first step this is zero), and how many are partially overlapping  (in this first step this is 1), where "i" represents the step of the iteration for refinement.

2.3.2) remove all the squares from the grid that belong to NFULLOUT(i). At step zero this routine is not providing any result as there is only one partial element in the solution arrays.

2.3.4) calculate the refinement factor by RF =  M /( summation of QTY(1:R))

2.3.5) calculate the new length of square side by L(1) = L(0)/ RF;

2.3.6) if L(i) > 0 then re-loop from 2) else break.

3) after break, divide et impera for improvement

3.1) for each single row of the grid try to shift the entire row of about half side length on the right and on the left, calculate efficiency and decide what's better. then you shift that line of the amount tried and verified as better, proceed again choosing left and right with 1/4 side length and so on up to when you get a lower efficiency than previous step.

NOTE: this last divide et impera section is only to be applied if you weight each single partial element with a weight between O and 1. If you consider partial covering elements as fully covering elements this is not providing you with any improvement.

FINAL NOTE: consider that you may apply a scaling factor to RF, for example at first passage the scaling factor will give you RF = M, possibly bringing you out of constraints immediately. Whenever you get an RF > 2 you may apply a 0.8 factor to RF if your usual number of elements in is the range of 100-1000 elements or even more.

FINAL NOTE 2: if you could remove the constraint that the squares shall have all the same length then it becomes a lot easier, and most of all a lot faster as you refine only approaching the boundaries.

Sorry if this is not really a formula, but I think it is one of the fastest elements that let you stay away from complicate meshing algos that you could take from computational analysis.
I also apologize for the uncommon notation. I tried my best to explain myself, I'm not used to standard notations.

Comment: This is clearly a well researched and thought out answer, but it's very difficult to understand the jargon and esoteric notation.  Can you please explain (among others) what OCS is, and what the notations (1:i:2), T:T(x,y) -> T(x-dx, y-dy), QTY(1:R) etc. mean?

Comment: sorry, you perfectly right.. i know I was supposed to use std notation, but I'm too far from school time. 1:x:R, means (in some kind of Matlab notation) that x iterates between 1 and R (that is constant or known variable at run time). OCS means Othogonal Coordinate System. T is the standard math notation for a function of two variables that map the point (x,y) into a new point of coordinates (x-dx, y-dy).

Comment: @Stephen H I did a little count to better reshape the statement "your usual number of elements in is the range of 100-1000 elements or even more". Actually a good improvement to shoose the starting lenth and cut some first iterations is to calculate the minimum radius MINR of the spline passing through the shape vertexes and start with a side length of MINR/2.5 or MINR/3.